# Reading TValue from TRttiProperty fails (Property Type: set of Byte)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I defined a type for set of Byte, an interface and a class that implements the interface.
The interface has a property of type **TTestSetofByte** + getter and setter. Nothing special at all.

```
type
 TTestSetOfByte = set of Byte;
  ITestInterface = interface
    ['{BCF0CEC2-F999-4E8A-A732-416F343C1629}']
    function GetPropSetOfByte: TTestSetOfByte;
    procedure SetPropSetOfByte(const Value: TTestSetOfByte);
    property PropSetOfByte: TTestSetOfByte read GetPropSetOfByte write SetPropSetOfByte;
  end;

  TTestClass3 = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterface)
  private
    FSetOfByte: TTestSetOfByte;
    function GetPropSetOfByte: TTestSetOfByte;
    procedure SetPropSetOfByte(const Value: TTestSetOfByte);
  public
    constructor Create;
    property PropSetOfByte: TTestSetOfByte read GetPropSetOfByte write SetPropSetOfByte;
  end;
```

The problem is that when I try to read the Value of the **PropSetOfByte** property delphi throws an **EAccessViolation** and I do not understand why. Properties of other types(int, string) work just fine.

Here is the test code:

```
procedure TTestUtlRttiComparer.DeleteMe;
var
  i: Integer;
  Instance1: ITestInterface;
  Object1: TObject;
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  RttiProp: TRttiProperty;
  RttiValue1: TValue;
  Type1: TRttiType;
begin
  Instance1 := TTestClass3.Create;
  Check(Instance1.PropSetOfByte = [1,4], 'Making sure getter works!');
  Instance1.PropSetOfByte := [3,4];
  Check(Instance1.PropSetOfByte = [3,4], 'Making sure setter works!');

  Object1 := (Instance1 as TObject);
  Check(Assigned(Object1));

  RttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    Type1 := RttiContext.GetType(Object1.ClassInfo);

    // Properties pruefen
    for i := 0 to High(Type1.GetProperties) do
    begin
      RttiProp :=  Type1.GetProperties[i];
      if RttiProp.Name = 'PropSetOfByte' then
      begin
        RttiValue1 := RttiProp.GetValue(Object1); // THIS CHECK FAILS with EACESSVIOLATION!!!
      end;
    end;
  finally
    RttiContext.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am using XE-2.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the compiler generate RTTI for properties of set types?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes when `TRttiType.GetValue()` (more specifically, the `Invoke()` function in the `System.Rtti` unit) tries to call `TTestClass3.GetPropSetOfByte()`.  The correct `Self` pointer is being passed in, but the `Result` parameter is nil, so a crash occurs when `GetPropSetOfByte()` tries to assign `FSetOfByte` to `Result`.

In short, the call stack is not being setup correctly by the RTTI system for `Set`-based properties.  I have reproduced the crash in XE2, XE6, and XE7, and have filed a bug report with Embarcadero:

TRttiProperty.GetValue() crash on Set-based property
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10206

Comment: thanks for looking into it. Reading your answer it seems you debugged this yourself. Which Delphi Compiler did you use? Hopefully this is fixed in later versions.
Can you think of any workaround to get at the TValue?

Comment: I debugged it using XE2, since that is the version you are using.  I will test it with some later versions and see if the same problem still happens.

Comment: Still crashes in XE6.  My XE7 VM is not working right now, so I can't check if XE7 also crashes.

Comment: I was able to finally test it in XE7 - it still crashes.  So I have filed a bug report for you: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10206

Comment: Thank you! Let's hope it gets adressed soon!

Comment: It seems that the complete handling of sets that are bigger than 4 bytes is broken in the Rtti - see my comment in the issue.